# Ruby: How do I get items out of an array?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
array = ["a","b","c"]
```

How do I get this:

```
"a","b","c"
```

I need to get the items out of the array, each double-quoted, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.collect { |a| "\"#{a}\"" }.join(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just started to learn ruby, I guess:

```
return ["a","b","c"].map{|i| '"' + i + '"'}.join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Might you want to get this:

```
irb(main):009:0> [1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s).join('","')
=> "1\",\"2\",\"3"
```

`"a","b","c"` this is not abject (these are 3 objects). But in ruby any code returns object value. So you should know what you want to get: 1 object (I returning string in this example) or various. If you want to get 3 objects you should extract array like this:

```
a, b, c = [1,2,3].map(&:to_s)
```